# Exclude the 14th column in loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to exclude the 14th column in the execution of my code.
Here's the snippet:

```
For Each xRow In xRg.Rows
    xStr = ""

    For Each xCell In xRow.Cells
        xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & Chr(59)
    Next

    While Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(59) & xCell.Column <> 14
       xStr = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)   
    Wend
Next
```

Comment: This `Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(59) & xCell.Column <> 14` should be `Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(59) And xCell.Column <> 14` I think.

Comment: I think the preoblem is with xCell. That ist your looping Variable in the for-loop. It is always set to the last cell in the for-loop. Unless this is intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should exclude the column 14 in the `For Loop` instead like this...

```
For Each xCell In xRow.Cells
    If xCell.Column <> 14 Then xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & Chr(59)
Next
```